# Excel duplicates in one column based on another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, duplicate

Hoping someone can assist with this.  We have a spreadsheet with data as below:

```
A       B   C   D       E           F   G
777142  233 4   45151   te01-ccm    0
777303  233 6   45151   te01-ccm    0
775827  233 6   53922   rk01-ccm    0
777238  233 6   55520   rk01-ccm    0
775603  233 6   61139   te01-ccm    0
775824  233 6   61408   rk01-ccm    0
777833  233 6   67884   tt01-ccm    0
777837  233 6   74772   tt01-ccm    0
777838  233 4   82364   tt01-ccm    0
777809  233 4   87726   tt01-ccm    0
774541  233 4   87833   tt01-ccm    0
774550  233 4   87833   tt01-ccm    0
774560  233 4   87833   tt01-ccm    0
777128  233 6   90486   te01-ccm    0
775396  233 6   90741   nh01-ccm    0
777092  233 4   91310   te01-ccm    0
774568  233 6   91839   tt01-ccm    0
775398  233 6   100230  nh01-ccm    0
775677  233 6   101461  te01-ccm    0
777206  233 4   101772  rk01-ccm    0
777188  233 6   107519  rk01-ccm    0
775819  233 4   108333  rk01-ccm    0
775831  233 6   108333  rk01-ccm    0
775813  233 6   109686  rk01-ccm    0
```

What I need to be able to do is have a "Y" in column G for records where:

- Column C = 4
- & if Column D is a duplicate then there is not a Column C = 6 for that D.

For example:

```
Row 1: C=4 D=45151, however Row 2: C=6 D=45151 so G = " ".
Row 9: C=4 D=82364, no duplicate D row so G = "Y".
```

I have tried a number of different IF/COUNTIF combinations but have had no success so far.  Any help really appreciated.

**tip2tail**

Comment: Are any duplicates always guaranteed to be contiguous?  Is Col D guaranteed to be in ascending order?  Can there be more than one duplicate for a value in D?

Comment: If there is a duplicate with a 4 and a 6, will the 4 record always precede the 6?

Comment: @fixer1234 There can be more than one C=4 for any D value, only ever will be 0 or 1 C=6.  D will always be in ascending order.  C=4 will always be before C=6 for any D value.

Comment: formula or macro?

Comment: @Raystafarian Any way that works! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution.  Assume the first data row is row 2.  I stuck 100 in as the last data row; make that whatever it is (or you can get fancy with functions and calculate it).  Formula for G2:

```
    =IF(AND(C2=4,OFFSET(D2,MATCH(6,C3:C$100,0),0,1)=D2),"Y"," ")
```

Copy that down for all data rows.  Note that the last entry will be #NA.  If it matters that it is not a blank, you can get fancy with IFNA or IFERROR, or just leave the last cell blank since it can never be "Y".

Edit: After figuring out the logic, I realized that you can use a simpler formula.  I'll show it separately in case you have already implemented the original.  The match and offset functions accomplish the same thing as a vlookup.  This formula will do the same thing:

```
    =IF(AND(C2=4,VLOOKUP(6,C3:D$100,2,0)=D2),"Y"," ")
```